# How to execute a python discord bot function in another python script?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to create a python script that would mute the users of a specific voice channel when executed. Till now I am able to mute everyone by typing the command in the discord text channel, but I would like to mute everyone when another python script tells the bot to. Below is my attempt to do that.

**bot.py** is the python discord bot:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from time import sleep

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="./")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online. ")

@client.command()
async def play_music_test():
    channel = await client.get_channel(voice_channel_number)
    voice = await channel.connect()
    await voice.play(
        discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/Users/USER/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe",
                               source="C:/Users/USER/Desktop/song.mp3"))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

**abc.py** is the other python script trying to call a function:

```
from bot import play_music_test
import asyncio

print("")
asyncio.run(play_music_test())
```

I ran the `bot.py` first and then tried to execute the `abc.py` next, bot came online but when executing `abc.py`, it didn't print or do anything at all. I just started to learn `discord.py` so if this is a silly question, forgive me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of running the python file you can import it, or making it a cog
heres an example:

importing: bot.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from time import sleep
from abc import *

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="./")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online. ")

@client.command(name = "play_music", aliases = ["you can asign aliases like this", "multiple ones too"])
async def play_music_test(ctx, channel): # If the python file doesn't know what channel is, it can be asigned when calling the function in discord, think of it like sys.argv or argparse
    if channel == None: channel = ctx.channel # This sets the current channel you are in if none was provided when executing it in discord    
#    channel = await client.get_channel(channel) now you don't need this line
    voice = await channel.connect()
    await voice.play(
        discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/Users/USER/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe",
                               source="C:/Users/USER/Desktop/song.mp3"))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

importing: abc.py
`remove asyncio.run(play_music_test())`
use it in discord instead! ex. play_music_test #general

Making it a cog: bot.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from time import sleep
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="./")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online. ")



for filename in os.listdir("./"):
    if filename == "bot.py": continue
    else: client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Making it a cog: abc.py

```
from bot import play_music_test
import asyncio
class Mycog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
    


    @client.command(name = "play_music", aliases = ["you can asign aliases like this", 
    "multiple ones too"])
    async def play_music_test(ctx, channel): # If the python file doesn't know what 
    channel is, it can be asigned when calling the function in discord, think of it like sys.argv or argparse
        if channel == None: channel = ctx.channel # This sets the current channel you are in if none was provided when executing it in discord    
    #    channel = await client.get_channel(channel) now you don't need this line
        voice = await channel.connect()
        await voice.play(
            discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/Users/USER/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe",
                                   source="C:/Users/USER/Desktop/song.mp3"))




def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Mycog(client))
```

This anwser is not the best but hope this helps!

Comment: The main problem I am trying to tackle is to call the function from external python code, rather than calling it in discord chat. Let me explain. I am trying to create a python GUI that will play different sounds or songs in the discord voice channel. So how to create a function that will play a sound when I click a button in the python GUI? ( I guess we cannot do such a thing )

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure, if i really understand, what you try to do, but to open a script from another script, i use [subprocess.Popen()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

but i think, in your case it fits more, to change the way you try to solve your problem. maybe you should take a look into the `on_message` event and use [message.content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.content)
?

Comment: When I execute abc.py, I would like to mute everyone in the Voice Channel. I need some sort of way to command the bot to mute, not by typing the command in the Discord chat but rather by executing abc.py. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can importing your `client` variable (`from bot import play_music_test, client`) and then `client.loop.create_task(play_music_test())`

(Although I do not understand why you would do such a thing)